# Preserving coordinates when converting TIFF image to numpy ndarray

Tags: python, raster, numpy, pandas, rioxarray

I have satellite image that I want to convert into numpy array (and then to Pandas).
I already know how to do that, but the problem is that it does not preserve the coordinate data.

This is how I do it now:

```
import xarray
src=rasterio.open('14072020.tif')
array = src.read()

pd.DataFrame(array.reshape([13,-1]).T)
```

I have also tried to follow this answer ([keeping the coordinate system of raster files in the resulting raster file after operation with numpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40578/keeping-the-coordinate-system-of-raster-files-in-the-resulting-raster-file-after))
but I always get this error:

> NameError: name 'gdal_array' is not defined

which does not allow me to open the image.

My end goal is to have Pandas table that contains  the bands values together with the coordinate values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert raster to CSV with lat, lon, and value columns](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358051/convert-raster-to-csv-with-lat-lon-and-value-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `open_rasterio` and `to_dataframe` methods to accomplish that.

```py
import rioxarray

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio("file.tif")
rds.to_dataframe()
```

See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358057/144357

Answer (score 1):

I would read with gdal and dump that to a numpy array.  ReadAsArray().

Coordinates and projection are obtained using the GetGeotransform() SetGeotransform() and the GetProjection() and SetProjection() applied to the data set.

Example here. https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html